# AngularJs: Nested UI-Bootstrap accordion not working, when update list value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion, angularjs-ng-repeat

I generate **"ui-bootstrap accordion"** by `ng-repeat`. I want upddate value of list dynamically. But when I update nested list value, `second accordion` is not working.

```
    <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <uib-accordion-group heading="{{prInfo.name}}"
            data-ng-repeat="(a,prInfo) in allPersonInfoNames | filter:prSearchFilter">
            Below iss the inner accordion
            <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
                <uib-accordion-group heading="Static Payroll Header, inner accordion"
                    data-ng-repeat="(b,payroll) in prInfo.banks">
                    This content is straight in the template.
                </uib-accordion-group>
            </uib-accordion>

        </uib-accordion-group>
        <uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups1">
            {{group.content}}
        </uib-accordion-group>
    </uib-accordion>
```

This code is work correctly, but when I generate  list of `banks` after loading the html, `accordion` not working.

> add `ng-click="getBanks(prInfo)"` to first accordion:

```
<uib-accordion-group heading="{{prInfo.name}}"
   data-ng-repeat="(a,prInfo) in allPersonInfoNames | filter:prSearchFilter"
   ng-click="getBanks(prInfo)">

$scope.getBanks = (personInfo) ->
        $scope.prResPromise = Cartable.httpReq('GET', "getBanks/#{personInfo.dbId}", null, (res) ->
          if res.isSuccess
            pi = _.findWhere($scope.allPersonInfoNames, {'dbId' : personInfo.dbId})
            index = $scope.allPersonInfoNames.indexOf(pi)
            $scope.allPersonInfoNames[index] = res
```

After this change, nested accordion is not working and first accordion doesn't open and second accordion doesn't generate.

If I set all accrodion to be open, both accordion work correctly, but when when I want open one of them, the problem accur again.

I do this with bootstrap accordion, but have this problem again.

Comment: Any plunker or jsfiddle to have a look at full code?

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban I have try to add a plunker.

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban When I try to add plunker, I found the problem. The problen is the version of `ui-bootstrap', I change version from 0.3 to 2.3.1 and the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by 2 step,

first update the version of `ui-bootstrap` from `0.3` to `2.3.1`, and then add specifice `is-open` to each of `accordion`.

```
            <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime1">
                <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="prInfo.isOpen" heading="{{prInfo.name}}"
                     ng-repeat="prInfo in allPersonInfoNames">
                    <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime2">
                        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="{{payroll.logPeriod.name}}"
                             is-open="payroll.isOpen"
                             ng-repeat="payroll in prInfo.payrolls">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <h1>in nested accordion</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </uib-accordion>
                </div>
            </uib-accordion>
```